# Non-blocking Assert counterpart

Tags: c#, unit-testing

What is the non-blocking counterpart of `Assert`, currently such methods as `AreEqual` (on failure) throw an exception and hold.

I would like to run all tests with reports, without any interaction from user.

Update, trivial example:

```
Assert.AreEqual(3,5);
Assert.AreEqual(3,5);
```

Only the first will be executed, exception will be thrown. I would like to have no exceptions, not interactions, just a report stating two failures.

Comment: Each method ideally should only have one test, so returning a "test failed" result on the first Assert is usually "standard practice"... Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Am I understanding right, that you're basically asking for the test to continue running after it's encountered an error case, and continue to aggregate all the errors you run into after that?

Comment: @lc. I would like to run **all** unit tests, currently I can run tests until I have an error.

Comment: If something is broken before, why do you expect the rest of the test to 'succeed'? Sounds like you are doing something very wrong. Do you have all your tests in a single (unit test) method?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, exactly.

Comment: @greenoldman: There's a semantic difference that's going to cause confusion here. Most people write one unit-testing method per "unit test," so when you say you want the rest of your tests to run, you're really saying you want the rest of your *assertions* to run.

Comment: Can you post some of your test code? I think it's the best way to clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the non-blocking counterpart of `Assert`?

There isn't one, because typically there's not much use knowing which other assertions failed after the first one. However, there are a couple of things you could do to fudge it if you really wanted to.

One idea is to use a logging framework to simply output error messages along the way, particularly when there's a situation where you think the rest of the test may succeed.

```
_assertLogger.LogErrorIf(a.ID == 0, "a's ID was not set");
```

Another would be to wrap your assertions in a method that captures the results, and then produce an `AggregateException` out of the collection of exceptions that your assertions produced.

```
_assertions.Add(() => Assert.IsNotNull(a));
_assertions.Add(() => Assert.AreNotEqual(0, a.ID));
_assertions.ThrowIfError();
```

Comment: Thank you +1. I will keep it open for a while, maybe someone else will add more input. One clarification, Assert throws exception, not me, so I didn't produce any exceptions (I mean directly).

Comment: @greenoldman: It's likely that you will end up producing exceptions in failing cases without meaning to. For example, in the last code sample above, if the first assertion fails, then the next line will have a null reference exception before the Assert method even gets called. I think this is why most people don't find it to be beneficial to continue running a test after one aspect of it has failed.

Answer (score 1):

I will give a practice answer - Write **one** assertion per test (method). This way, if an assertion fails, other tests would run anyway.

So your example should really be:

```
[Test]
public void ThreeShouldEqualFive(){
    Assert.AreEqual(3,5);
}

[Test]
public void ThreeShouldEqualFour(){
    Assert.AreEqual(3,4);
}
```

This is the recommended way to write tests anyway (though not possible to keep to one assertion per test in all the cases.)

Comment: Ok, I reproduced this, and still VS stops in tracks, showing me exception box.

Comment: What VS do you use? Me -- 2010.